# Не проходит лимит по времени (считаем числа с определёной суммой цифр и делимостью)

Tags: python, c++

Подсчитать сколько целых чисел в диапазоне `[a, b]` делятся на 11 и имеют сумму цифр в диапазоне `[c, d]`. Ограничения `1 ≤ a ≤ b < 10^18`, `1 ≤ с ≤ d < 163`. Время расчета не более двух секунд.

Пример:

> ```
> Вход: a = 11, b = 40, c = 3, d = 6
> Выход: 2
> ```

`Python`:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
c, d = map(int, input().split())
count = 0
i = a
while i % 11 != 0:
    i = i + 1
first = i
for k in range(first, b+1, 11):
    s = sum(map(int, str(k)))
    if c <= s <= d:
        #print (k, s)
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

`C++`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int digitsSum(int n) {
  int sum = 0;
  while (n != 0) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main() {
  long int a, b, c, d, kil = 0;
  cin >> a >> b;
  cin >> c >> d;
  int first = a;
  while (first % 11 != 0) {
    first++;
  }
  for (int i = first; i <= b+1; i = i + 11) {
    if (i % 11 == 0 && c <= digitsSum(i) && digitsSum(i) <= d) {
      kil = kil + 1;
    }
  }
  cout << kil;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте применить динамическое программирование - сколько N-значных чисел, начинающихся с цифры M, имеют сумму цифр S. Должно работать несколько быстрее, чем цикл от одного до 10 в 18 степени...

Comment: Кстати, URL проверяющей системы есть?

Comment: да есть https://algotester.com/uk/ArchiveProblem/DisplayWithFile/40569

Comment: Да спасибо за помощь Мне интересен любой другоїй подход   Мне удалось только пока  найти закономеірность в количестве чисел,  что делятся на 11  В 2 х цифрових  9 таких чисел , в  3х - 81, В 4х - 819,  в 5 - 8181, в 6х - 81819  надо ще найти закономеірность в суме цифр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша попытка решить задачу правильная, но не достаточно быстрая. На моей машине простейший цикл на Питоне делает 24 миллиона итераций в секунду. В худшем случае нам нужно сделать `10^18 / 11` итераций.

`(10^18 / 11) / (24 * 10^6) ~= 4 * 10^9 секунд ~= 123 года`

Быстрые оценки показывают, что пробему не решить заменой языка программирования. Даже если C++ в сто раз быстрее Питона вы получите один год работы, а требуется две секунды. Делайте прикидки чтобы не тратить зря время.

Пусть `F(A, r)` - множество элементов множества `A` которые при делении на `11` дают остаток `r`.

Обозначим через `A + x` множество каждый элемент которого есть сумма элемента из `A` и числа `x`.

Свойство `F(A, r) + x = F(A + x, (r + x) mod 11)` проверяется непосредственно.

Пусть `G(A, s)` - множество элементов множества `A` у которых сумма цифр меньше `s`.

Вычислим `G([0, n), s)`. Пусть десятичная запись `n` имеет вид `dXX...X`, где `d` - цифра в старшем разряде. Имеем `n = dXX...X = 100...0 + (d-1)XX...X`.

Полуинтервал `[0, dXX...X)` разобьём на два `[0, 100...0) + [100...0, dXX...X)` (здесь `+` - объединение множеств).

Тогда `G([0, dXX...X), s) = G([0, 100...0), s) + G([100...0, dXX...X), s)`.

Свойство `G([100...0, dXX...X), s) = G([0, (d-1)XX...X), s - 1) + 100...0` проверяется непосредственно.

Обозначим `Н(A, s, r) = F(G(A, s), r)`.

```
H([0, dXX...X), s, r) =
= F(G([0, dXX...X), s), r) =
= F(G([0, 100...0), s) + G([100...0, dXX...X), s), r) =
= F(G([0, 100...0), s), r) + F(G([100...0, dXX...X), s), r) =
= H([0, 100...0), s, r) + F(G([0, (d-1)XX...X), s - 1) + 100...0, r) =
= H([0, 100...0), s, r) + (F(G([0, (d-1)XX...X), s - 1), (r - 100...0) mod 11) + 100...0) =
= H([0, 100...0), s, r) + (H([0, (d-1)XX...X), s - 1, (r - 100...0) mod 11) + 100...0).
```

Обозначим `h(n, s, r) = |H([0, n), s, r)|`. Получаем:

```
h(dXX...X, s, r) =
= h(100...0, s, r) + h((d-1)XX...X, s - 1, (r - 100...0) mod 11).
```

Ещё одно тождество, которое будет нужно:

```
h(100...0, s, r) =
= h(10...0, s, r) + h(90...0, s - 1, (r - 10...0) mod 11).
```

Оба тождества объединяются вместе. По `n` вычисляем `m` - максимальная степень 10 меньшая `n`. Тогда

```
h(n, s, r) = h(m, s, r) + h(n - m, s - 1, (r - m) mod 11).
```

База.

```
h(n<=0, ?, ?) = 0
h(?, s<=0, ?) = 0
h(n=1, s>0, r!=0) = 0
h(n=1, s>0, r=0) = 1
```

Функцию `h` нужно кешировать, иначе повторяющиеся вычисления убьют всю скорость.

Последнии шаг. Мы имеем вычислять `h` на прямоугольниках `[0, n)*[0, s)`. А нам нужны `[n1, n2)*[s1, s2)`.

```
h([n1, n2)*[s1, s2)) =
= h([n1, n2)*[0, s2)) - h([n1, n2)*[0, s1)) =
= (h([0, n2)*[0, s2)) - h([0, n1)*[0, s2))) -
-(h([0, n2)*[0, s1)) - h([0, n1)*[0, s1))) =
= h(n2, s2) - h(n1, s2) - h(n2, s1) + h(n1, s1)
```

Теперь код:

```
import functools


def ten_pow_below(n):
    m = 1
    while 10 * m < n:
        m *= 10
    return m


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def h(n, s, r):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if s <= 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        if r == 0:
            return 1
        return 0

    m = ten_pow_below(n)
    return h(m, s, r) + h(n - m, s - 1, (r - m) % 11)


def hh(n1, n2, s1, s2):
    return h(n2 + 1, s2 + 1, 0) - h(n1, s2 + 1, 0) - h(n2 + 1, s1, 0) + h(n1, s1, 0)


a, b = map(int, input().split())
c, d = map(int, input().split())
print(hh(a, b, c, d))
```

> ```
> $ echo -e "11 40\n3 6" | python digital_sum.py 
> 2
> ```

P.S. Вывод формулы слишком сложный. Но без него я делал заход за заходом не получая нужный результат. Если у вас есть идеи как объяснить проще, я с удовольствием поплюсую ваш ответ.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за детальное  объяснение формулы и за код!!!   Конечно, что наверное  сложно будет обьяснить  ученикам 7-9 класса ))  Теперь мне понятно почему задачу до Вас решили только 12 участников (из 3000 пользователей)) Не думаю что у меня получится проще, но если будут успешные идеи, напишу Я новичок здесь,  но надеюсь что мой плюс на Ваш ответ вам зачислен :-) Успехов Вам и еще раз спасибо

Comment: У вас небольшая ошибка в коде - функция hh обращается к глобальной переменной вместо аргумента.

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо! Надо было слушаться маму и никогда не писать код на верхнем уровне модуля. Не первый раз уже так ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Та же идея, что и у Станислава, только сначала вычисляется H(...) для всех степеней 10, возможных сумм цифр и модулей, что потом переиспользуется в вычислении.

И, конечно, без возмутительной элегантности питона.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
 
using namespace std;
 
unsigned short mod11(int value)
{
    short mod = value % 11;
    if (mod < 0)
    {
        mod += 11;
    }
    return mod;
}
 
size_t sum_array[19][163][11] = {};
 
template <typename T>
T myPow(T x, int p)
{
    if (p == 0)
        return 1;
    if (p == 1)
        return x;
    return myPow(x, p - 1) * x;
}
 
int len(size_t x)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (; x >= 10; ++result)
    {
        x /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
 
int left_digit(size_t x)
{
    return x / myPow(10UL, len(x) - 1);
}
 
size_t remove_left_digit(size_t x)
{
    return x - left_digit(x) * myPow(10UL, len(x) - 1);
}
 
int update_mod(int old_mod, int first_digit, int deg)
{
    return mod11(old_mod + first_digit * myPow(-1, deg % 2));
}
 
void initialize_pow_of_10(size_t (&sum_array)[19][163][11])
{
    for (int sum = 0; sum < 163; ++sum)
    {
 
        sum_array[0][sum][0] = 1;
    }
 
    for (int deg = 1; deg < 19; ++deg)
    {
        for (int sum = 0; sum < 163; ++sum)
        {
            for (unsigned short mod = 0; mod < 11; ++mod)
            {
                for (int first_digit = 0; first_digit <= min(sum, 9); ++first_digit)
                {
                    int new_mod = update_mod(mod, first_digit, deg);
                    sum_array[deg][sum][mod] += sum_array[deg - 1][sum - first_digit][new_mod];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
size_t count_below_sum_below_x_mod11(int sum, int mod, unsigned long x)
{
 
    int n_digits = len(x);
 
    int first_digit = left_digit(x);
    if (n_digits == 1)
    {
        return mod <= x && mod <= sum ? 1 : 0;
    }
 
    size_t result = 0;
 
    for (int start_digit = 0; (start_digit < first_digit) && (start_digit <= sum); ++start_digit)
    {
        int new_mod = update_mod(mod, start_digit, n_digits);
        result += sum_array[n_digits - 1][sum - start_digit][new_mod];
    }
    int new_mod = update_mod(mod, first_digit, n_digits);
    result += count_below_sum_below_x_mod11(sum - first_digit, new_mod, remove_left_digit(x));
 
    return result;
}
 
size_t count_divisible_by_11(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, int sum_min, int sum_max)
{
    return count_below_sum_below_x_mod11(sum_max, 0, b) + count_below_sum_below_x_mod11(sum_min - 1, 0, a - 1) -
           count_below_sum_below_x_mod11(sum_min - 1, 0, b) - count_below_sum_below_x_mod11(sum_max, 0, a - 1);
}
 
int main()
{
    initialize_pow_of_10(sum_array);
 
    int sum_min, sum_max;
    size_t a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cin >> sum_min >> sum_max;
 
    cout << count_divisible_by_11(a, b, sum_min, sum_max) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Плюсик за "возмутительную элегантность питона". :)